# Como saber en que expansión panel el usuario clica

Tags: angular

¿Como puedo saber donde clica el usuario?

```
<mat-accordion">
  <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let Questionnaire of questionnaires" hideToggle>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
        {{Questionnaire.name}}
      </mat-panel-title>
      <mat-panel-description>
        {{Questionnaire.description}}
      </mat-panel-description>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <div mat-dialog>
      {{Questionnaire.question}}
    </div>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
  </mat-accordion>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro de tu mat-expansion-panel podrías usar un mat-action-row, ejemplo:

```
<mat-action-row>
  <button mat-button (click)="doSomething(Questionnaire)"> Your Text</button>
</mat-action-row>
```

Y en tu archivo .ts creas la funcion que reciba el objeto o lo que desees recibir y manipulas los datos etc,
para mas información puedes consultar los [ejemplos](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/examples)

Comment: Muchas gracias LordOfLies por tu respuesta. La verdad que no me lo había planteado realizar así, ya que me gustaría que fuera más dinámica la selección y se ejecute la función cuando pulso en el <mat-expansion-panel-header>. Pero probaré a hacerlo así como segunda opción.

Comment: Entonces agrega el (click)="doSomething()" en tu <mat-expansion-panel-header>

Comment: Pues parece que si funciona... Muchas gracias!!!!